# How to implement an iterator in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying to implement an iterator in Julia, but get an exception when the for-loop tries to call `start` already.

Here is what I get (I ran include(...), then `using RDF`):

```
julia> methods(start)
# 1 method for generic function "start":
start(graph::Graph) at /Users/jbaran/src/RDF.jl/src/RDF.jl:214

julia> for x in g
       println(x)
       end
ERROR: `start` has no method matching start(::Graph)
 in anonymous at no file
```

The function definition in the `RDF` module looks like this at the moment:

```
function start(graph::Graph)
    return GraphIterator(collect(keys(graph.statements)), nothing, nothing, nothing, [], [])
end
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't forget to specify `Base.` - you are adding methods to an existing function.

```
module MyMod
  type Blah
    data
  end
  export Blah
  Base.start(b::Blah) = 1
  Base.done(b::Blah,state) = length(b.data) == state-1
  Base.next(b::Blah,state) = b.data[state], state+1
end
using MyMod
x = Blah([1,2,3])
for i in x
  println(i)
end
```

This works as of Julia 0.3.

Comment: Ah. Adding "Base." to `start`, `done` and `next` did it. I will need to look once more into scoping. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you don't want to have to prefix `Base.` in front of every method you define, you can explicitly import it via `import Base: start, done next` at the top of your module.

Comment: It is good practice to prefix `Base` to prevent collisions.

Answer (score 11):

In Julia 1.+, you should implement:

1. `Base.iterate(::YourType)` for the starting iteration,
2. `Base.iterate(::YourType, state)` for following iterations while getting the `state` from the previous steps.

Both methods should return `(result, state)` tuple, except for the last iteration that should return `nothing`.

In practice, this means that iterating on `x::YourType` with

```
for i in x
    # some code
end
```

is a shorthand for writing

```
it = iterate(x)
while it !== nothing
    i, state = it
    # some code
    it = iterate(x, state)
end
```

See the [manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Building off of @BoZenKhaa's answer, a common pattern is

```
Base.iterate(yt::YourType, state=1) = state > length(yt) ? nothing : (yt.data[state],state+1)
```

where `YourType` has a field `data` which can be indexed as an array, with `state` holding the index.
Along with `state=1`, the right hand side uses the [ternary operator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/control-flow/#man-conditional-evaluation) to combine lines 1+2, returning `nothing` if at the end or if in bounds a tuple of the element at that state and the next state.