# julia iteration : start, next, done side effects

Tags: julia

Iteration in Julia can be achieved for a new defined type by implementing the iteration interface that has the 3 functions: `start`, `next`, `done`

I see no exclamation point on the end of those functions so from my understanding of julia naming conventions these 3 functions should not modify their arguments. In particular these two loops should give the same output

```
state = start(iter)
while !done(iter, state)
    (i, state) = next(iter, state)
    @show i
end


state = start(iter)
while !done(iter, state)
    (other_i, other_state) = next(iter, state)
    (i, state) = next(iter, state)
    @show i
end
```

Am I wrong? I ask because I bumped into some iterators in external julia packages not respecting this.

Comment: In general iterators should be immutable anyway, as altering the contents *during* an iteration is dangerous business, so it wouldn't make sense to use a mutating function on them. As for mutating `state`, I suppose there's no `!` in the name because even though in theory the `next` function *could* mutate the received `state` object and simply return it again, rather than just returning a new state object, in practice the `state` object is not supposed to be manipulated directly, but is meant to be internal to the `for` statement, as is `next`. So presumably lack of ! is just for consistency.

Comment: Which package was it you spotted the "disrespectful behaviour"? :p

Comment: Thanks for your clarification @TasosPapastylianou. Don't worry about the package, it will be fixed.

Comment: oh, I'm not saying there's anything that necessarily needs fixing per se. Mutating the intrinsic `state` variable isn't a big deal (might even be a more efficient way of implementing an iterator). I was just curious where you saw it so I could have a look :D

Comment: For anyone coming across this question with Julia 1+, iterators are implemented differently, see the [manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/) or for example this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028539/how-to-implement-an-iterator-in-julia/64419278#64419278

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If possible, those functions are not supposed to mutate the iterator (such that the iterator state can be copied and re-used). However, there are some prominent examples where such a design is not possible, or only possible with significant performance penalties. The prime example of this is `Base.Task`, which is iterable (each iteration running until the next `produce` statement):

```
julia> collect(@async for i = 1:10
       produce(i)
       end)
10-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
```

In those cases we've generally been fine with mutation (though of course any use of the iteration protocol that caches states won't work). The exclamation point at the end of functions is a convention, but is not enforced in any way (and is not strictly limited to mutation of its input arguments, but rather having some side effect that you want to make sure the programmer is aware of).

Comment: `Base.Eachline` is another prime example of a mutating iterator, in base.

Comment: This is correct. To elaborate a bit, some objects naturally support state changes that we don't consider mutations; for example reading from a file updates the file position, but we don't use the name `read!` for this. Mutation doesn't seem to be quite the right concept in these cases.

Answer (score 3):

Those methods should **not** modify their arguments, probably because you may want to re-use an iterator, and you're right about the exclamation **mark**.

And you are right, the custom is to append **!** to method names if they modify their arguments

I've also come across a package, the [ProgressMeter](https://github.com/timholy/ProgressMeter.jl) package which uses the method next!() and that one does change the progress-meter type that you have

I like the idea of the exclamation mark (I don't know if it originated in Julia or elsewhere) but surely its important for developers to be consistent with this

**tl;dr**
You are right, it says so in the docs, and to really cement the point, the section detailing it is called [Essentials](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/base/#essentials)

(note to non-native English speakers, there is no such thing as an exclamation point)

Comment: do you mean in terms of having to explicitly write the loop in the format about? or would a `for` statement respect `next!`? I somehow doubt this!

Comment: I dont understand what you're saying? Are you referring to the ProgressMeter package? or something else

Comment: I confess I haven't looked at the package; but, the `next()` function is used internally by the `for` statement, right? How does defining a `next!` function help with using an iterator in a `for` statement? Does the `for` statement look for a `next!()` function too? Or have I misunderstood what you're saying?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, it's actually a `ProgressMeter.next!` function, just happens to have the same name, but nothing to do with `Base.next` or iterators. I think it's just a function to update the progress meter to show the next point. Sorry I thought you meant ProgressMeter was an iterator and that this function was somehow implicitly called inside a for loop.

Comment: no sorry what I said was bit of confusing. The ProgressMeter object (type)  that goes into the next!() method isnt an interator by itself, but a type that contains one and you **can** mess around with it, it has an **end** and a **start** but its supposed to be a simple way to make a progress meter, and I just used it as an example of a package with the next!() method. And the for-loop woulnt be iterating over the  ProgressMeter object, the progressmeter object has a predefined size by the user. I apologize, that example I gave had only a grain of relevance for what I was trying to convey

Comment: Oh I see so that method isnt even directly affiliated with the actual Julia workings, I feel silly now. I actually used ProgressMeter.next!() a couple of months before I ever started messing around directly with actual iterators with next() and start() and I was confused at first precisely by the method next() didn't have an exclamation mark, as that "version" had already sunk in with me and made perfect sense...now its preposterous

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And yes I am not a native speaker :)  But still... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclamation_mark

Comment: @IssamT. I guess what isebarn's trying to say is that "American English" isn't *real* English. bwahahahah :ppp